# Configuration settings properties read in dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, design-patterns, configuration

I have an application where I need to have configuration settings for specific business entities (namely countries). The config will go something like this:

```
<country value="US">
   <metadata>
      <key name="filePath" value="c:\blah">
      <key name="wsPath" value="http://blah.com">
   </metadata>
   <sublayouts>
     <template value="division">
       <key name="path" value="c:\blah\file.txt">
     </division>
   </sublayouts>
</country>
<country value="FR">
   <metadata>
      <key name="filePath" value="c:\blah">
      <key name="wsPath" value="http://blah.com">
   </metadata>
   <sublayouts>
     <template value="division">
       <key name="path" value="c:\blah\file.txt">
     </division>
   </sublayouts>
</country>
```

What I want is to be able to read this into a static object for the site I am in. So, for the US site, it will load in the entire country node that has value="US". Once loaded, I want to be able to read it like:

`string var = Config.metaData.filePath`

OR

`string var = Config.sublayouts.template["division"].path;`

Is this even doable? Is there a good design pattern (not too difficult) that does this? I am fully willing to change the structure of the XML as long as it makes sense. I want to be able to add in new sections when I want. Basically, the idea is to have a flexible configuration system that is not too hard to maintain programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of **Dynamic** in C# 4.0 with **ExpandoObject**. Data can be loaded from Xml into ExpandoObject dynamically by casting ExpandoObject to IDictionary, something like:

```
 dynamic country = new ExpandoObject();
 var countryDic = country as IDictionary<string, object>;

 dynamic metadata = new ExpandoObject();
 var metadataDic = metadata as IDictionary<string, object>;
 metadataDic["filePath"] = "your file path";

 countryDic["metadata"] = metadata;
 var filePath = country.metadata.filePath;
```

More information: [Introducing the ExpandoObject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/01/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject.aspx)

Comment: nice! Is there a way to set the name of the property dynamically also? something like: Country.Metadata = "blah" - but where the name "Metadata" is dynamic?

Comment: If you want all dynamic, declare Country as dynamic too: dynamic country = new ExpandoObject(); country.MetaData = metaData;

Comment: the string metadata will come from string somewhere else... do you know what is the syntax that would be for Country."metadata" = "asdasd" where "metadata" is a variable?

Comment: you can cast: var countryDic = country as IDictionary<string, object>; countryDic["metadata"] = metadata, with this way, it's easy to make property as variable

Comment: No, use countryDic to fill data for dynamic object country, then you still use dynamic from country like var metaData = country.MetaData. they are reference to each other

Comment: done, please, I dropped all classical definition by using all as dynamic

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is design your data containers first. In other words, you will end up with a class for each XML node type: Country and Template. You'll get something like this:

```
class Country {
  IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> MetaData {get;set;}
  IList<Template> Sublayouts {get;set;}
}
```

Once you've got that data you've got several options for serializing it to and from XML: DataContractSerializer, BinaryFormatter, XmlSerializer, etc.

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail? Is there a way I can not have concrete classes for them? I want to be able to add a section such as 'sublayouts' without adding another class..